# Defined Variable in PHP script has undefined variable error

Tags: php, wamp

I'm recieving an issue in the following php code. I am recieiving an unknown variable error in line 146, (echo $newrecord) variable. I'm not sure what is wrong with this variable, I have defined it in the IF statement, and am simply echoing if it is successful. I originally had that segment of code (after ) at the top of the script, but it was causing issues with the mandatory field error messages displaying properly. Any help is appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = $subErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = $sub = $newrecord = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["Name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["Name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["Email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Website"])) {
    $website = "";
  } else {
    $website = test_input($_POST["Website"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)) {
      $websiteErr = "Invalid URL"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["Comment"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
  } else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
  }

if (empty($_POST["Subscription"])) {
    $subErr = "Subscription is required"; }
 else {
    $sub = test_input($_POST["Subscription"]);
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>Southern Tier Daily News</h2>
<form method="post" action="Newspaper3.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true"/>

<img src="https://bloximages.newyork1.vip.townnews.com/dnews.com/content/tncms/custom/image/5eec4204-483e-11e6-93c8-97ef236dc6c5.jpg?_dc=1468334339" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px;">
    <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<fieldset>
 <legend>Newspaper Subscription Request</legend>  
  Name: <input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="Email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="Website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="Comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
  Subscription:
   <select name="Subscription">
       <option value=""></option>
   <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
   <option value="Evening">Evening</option>
   <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
   <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
</select> 
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $subErr;?></span>

  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
<br><br>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Visit Admin Page</a>
 </fieldset>
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $website;
echo "<br>";
echo $comment;
echo "<br>";
echo $gender;
echo "<br>";
echo $sub;
?>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

include('connect-mysql.php');

$fname = $_POST['Name'];
$femail = $_POST['Email'];
$fcomment = $_POST['Comment'];
$fsubsciption = $_POST['Subscription'];
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO newspaper (Name, Email, Comment, Subscription) VALUES ('$fname',
'$femail', '$fcomment', '$fsubsciption')";

      if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert))  {
           die('error inserting new record');       

  }     // end of nested if statement

        $newrecord = "1 record added to the database";

}  // end of main if statement

?>

<?php

echo $newrecord

?>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if the code inside the if is never executed?

Answer (score 2):

`newrecord` is defined and initialized inside the `if` statement, therefore if your code opts to the else, it will skip the `if` and your `newrecord` variable won't exist.

Answer (score 0):

`$newrecord` is defined within an if statement, when the if is not executed the variable is not available. You can define it by default adding `$newrecord = '';` before you start the if for the submit.

Comment: Ok that variable error is now gone, thanks! The web page loads properly now, but upon populating all fields and pressing Submit button I am getting back my "error inserting new record" defined error message displaying. Any ideas? I also noticed after clicking Submit, that I also have my "Gender is required" message displaying, and the value is being cleared out after pressing submit.